# Power BI CustomData not being passed to report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

The ability to pass a customdata string field into a token request is now available for Power BI. Apparently it should be available in the dataset itself via Dax filter methods ie using a
dax filter that looks like this

```
[State] = CUSTOMDATA()
```

I have followed all the available online instructions but the customdata that I am passing never seems to land in the report and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.
I know the other parameters that I am passing such as username, datasets and roles are all working as expected but customdata just does not seem to work.

Is anyone able to advise what I might be missing?
It never seems to come through. Any help would be appreciated. See screenshots below for what how I have implemented it.
Thanks

**Here is an example of the token request I am making**
[image: Here is an example of the token request I am making]

**Here is an example of the dax filter I created that is consuming the custom data**
[image: Here is an example of the dax filter I created that is consuming the custom data]

**I also tried adding the CustomData as a measure just to see it in the report (without applying any filtering)**
[image: Adding CustomData measure]

Comment: I have the exact same problem. how did you solve it ?

Comment: Unfortunately I didnt. I could not find a way around it and anyway we moved our RLS to the DB server instead. But I will likely need to get back to this. If you find a solution please post here.  Likewise I will to.